# function not implemented in this class - perl error

Tags: perl, yaml, cpan

http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MSTROUT/YAML-0.84/lib/YAML/Loader/Base.pm

If I am hitting

```
die 'load() not implemented in this class.';
```

What does that mean?

I am a complete perl newbie and trying to learn/debug why I am seeing this error.

Does that mean, I should have load() implemented somewhere else (overloaded) and I should not have reached here?

My code does:

```
try.pm

use YAML;
my $yaml = YAML::LoadFile( $params{'filename'} );
```

which goes to YAML.pm
which has:

```
field loader_class => 'YAML::Loader';
```

and calls LoadFile() and does:

```
Load(do { local $/; <$IN> });
```

which calls Load()

```
$yaml->loader_class($YAML::LoaderClass)
    if $YAML::LoaderClass;
```

And that gets to where I see the error:
YAML/Loader/Base.pm

Comment: Can you show us the code which is using `YAML::Loader` ?

Comment: Just updated my que with code.

Comment: The code you have works fine for me using 0.84.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YAML::Loader::Base is used as a base class to provide some common functionality. `load` must be overridden in base classes.

Try upgrading YAML. There appears to be a bug in your version.

Comment: Sadly, I am not in position to update entire YAML. I need to find out what bug you are talking about and if I can just fix that, that would be better for me. Please let me know if you know what bug we are talking about here. Appreciate your help.

Comment: See the OP for a description of the bug.

Comment: I did not get what you mean here.

Comment: Using YAML should give you this error. That it does is a bug.